# imagemap with imagemapster.js

Tags: javascript, html, imagemap, imagemapster

I am trying to create an html imagemap with highlighting.
I therefor use http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/ which did work on my tryouts, but does not work on the final map. The areas in the map seem to be correct - I did attach an click handler to them responding with the expected area. However, imagemapster does not highlight the areas.

What am I missing here?

Find my example here http://bernhardriegler.github.io/imagemap/index.html

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64711402/2397550

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer here:
[jQuery plugin imagemapster isn't doing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236848/jquery-plugin-imagemapster-isnt-doing-anything#answer-24143395)

imagemapster does require the href attribute on all areas you wish to highlight.